# Neo4J 2.01 Browser unresponsive

Tags: neo4j

I've upgraded Neo4J 2.0.1 from the Community Edition to the Enterprise edition on an x64 Windows server. I uninstalled the Community Edition version from Add/Remove programs first, then followed the instructions here:

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/server-installation.html

... to install the service. When I run bin\Neo4jInstaller.bat status it responds with "Running" - and it's up and running in the Windows services snap-in too (where I can stop and start it).

When I browse to localhost:7474/browser (using Chrome), however, none of the responses to any of the commands I am executing, including :help, are being displayed. And the links to the tutorial files don't work, either.

If I head to the localhost:7474/webadmin, however, everything seems fine? So I'm pretty sure Chrome is the problem - something is still sitting on it from when I was connecting to the Community version with it. So I've cleared my cache from Chrome since the upgrade, and removed the variables in local storage using "Inspect Element > Resources" (restarting Chrome each time) - but as yet, no joy, and no snazzy graphs in my browser, either.

One other thing - when I stop and start the service, Chrome does recognise it as "unplugged" and displays a message OK... It just doesn't seem to want to do anything else.

Any ideas?

Comment: Absolutely no urgency from my POV with this, by the way - I'm using Neo4J for my university research, and, while I need to run a service on the server, my preferred MO will be to download copies of the "live" database to my (nicer to use, replete with office software etc) local machine for analysis (using the Community edition) - just tested this with a database that I took from the live server and it works fine, so I'll never actually use the browser on the live one, anyway, I don't think. But it's perhaps useful for others to know about this issue.

Comment: Can you post some screenshots from the Network tab of your developer console in chrome while loading the page?

Comment: Sure: [link]http://www.trovo.co.uk/Images/StackOverflowScreenshots/Neo4JBrowser/NeoBrowserUnresponsiveInitialLoad.png shows the network diagnostic on the initial page load and [link]http://www.trovo.co.uk/Images/StackOverflowScreenshots/Neo4JBrowser/NeoBrowserUnresponsiveSimpleQueryForMatchAll%20Nodes.png shows it when I sent a simple query (which disappeared in Chrome with no response).

Comment: I may regret saying there was no urgency if it turns out that the REST api is broken, of course. Hopefully it ain't though.

Comment: Did you try private mode in chrome? And shift-reload to clear the js caches?

Comment: Just tried it with a shift reload and in an incognito window. Neither had any effect. It's this version of Chrome: Version 33.0.1750.146 m. Plus I can confirm that in all other respects the Neo Enterprise server seems to be working fine and dandy. Maybe it's something to do with running Chrome on a Win2008 R2 server, though it all worked fine when I was running the Neo Community version on this box... Also (perhaps rather embarrassingly) the box has IE11 on it, and it all works fine in that, too. :)